# How to rename folder containing files with VBA using statement Name As

Tags: vba, excel, directory, rename

Good Day,

I have a VBA Project where it automatically creates folder for some specific data categories based on their given names and ids (folder name would be ID_CategoryName). Therefore when i change or update the name of the category, i also want to update the folder name to represent the new name.

I am using the statement syntax **Name** to rename the folder as below:

```
Dim Fld1 as String
Dim Fld2 as String

Fld1 = "C:\Users\rapha\Desktop\1_Category1"
Fld2 = "C:\Users\rapha\Desktop\1_Category2"

If Dir(Fld1, vbDirectory) <> "" And Fld1 <> Fld2 Then
   Name Fld1 As Fld2
End if
```

---

**The problem:** It works for empty folders and renames them, however folders containing files returns me Error 75 Path/File Access error

---

**Solution:** I discovered that the problem itself is with renaming folders in my windows after i copy Microsoft Office Files (an instance of the Word opens in Task Manager). However i have chosen @Ashleedawg solution as it would resolve my problem or someone else's for the **Name As** statement, and it also helps me further in checking if someone else is using the folder/files or not (for shared drives).

---

**Additional Information:**

**1-** Not sure if question is duplicate, however all questions i found regarding folder renaming in VBA (here in stackoverflow) use a different method (FileSystemObject). If someone knowledgeable could tell me the difference in using **Name As** or **FileSystemObject**

**2-** I tested the following line in the immediate window:

```
Msgbox Dir("C:\Users\rapha\Desktop\Category1", vbDirectory)
```

It returns me "1_Category1", proving the existence of the directory

**3-** Is there a more efficient method for renaming folders/files?

**4-** I did some manual testing with syntax Name on immediate window. I've been putting a file in a folder by just dragging or using Ctrl + C, and some files gives me error, others don't. Example, i put a PDF or Word file with 300kb and whenever i run **Name** ThatFolder **As** ThatFolder2 it gives me error.

**5-** When i open Task Manager it says that there is a instance of Microsoft Word Open, even though it doesn't show in my Windows Interface. When i end the process  i am able to rename the folder. So it seems like when i copy a file it kind of opens the instance of that application and that stays open.

**6-** There is no open files in the folder, however i have another code that runs just before it that uses the objects in the folder. On a listbox_click event that is usually selected when you are changing the name of the folder.

```
Sub DirectorylistActivate(FPath As String, SH As Worksheet, INPUTFRM As UserForm, FILELSTNAME As String)

    Dim objFSO As Object, objFolder As Object, objFile As Object
    Dim z As Integer
    Dim rnglastrow As Range
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim fName As String   

        'Create an instance of the FileSystemObject
        Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        'Get the folder object
        Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(FPath)
        z = 1

        SH.UsedRange.Clear

        'loops through each file in the directory
        For Each objFile In objFolder.Files

             Set rng = SH.Range(SH.Cells(z + 1, 1), SH.Cells(z + 1, 1))

            'create hyperlink in range
             SH.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=rng, Address:= _
             objFile.Path, _
             TextToDisplay:=objFile.name
             z = z + 1

        Next objFile

        'check if directory is empty
        fName = Dir(FPath & "\", vbNormal)

        Set rnglastrow = DirectoryList.Range("A2:A" & lrow(SH, "A"))
        rnglastrow.name = "Datafiles"

        'if directory empty clear rowsource
        If fName = "" Then
            INPUTFRM.Controls(FILELSTNAME).RowSource = ""
        Else
            INPUTFRM.Controls(FILELSTNAME).RowSource = "DataFiles"
        End If

        Set objFile = Nothing
        Set objFSO = Nothing
        Set objFolder = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: I suspect if any files in that directory are open the rename will fail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd bet that the reason you're getting the error is because you have one or more files that are located in the folder currently **open**.

If all files are closed, the `Name..As` command functions properly to rename a folder, without error, *regardless* of whether there are files in the folder.

The only other (non-obvious) condition that will cause an error in this situation is trying to rename a folder "to" a new drive.

---

This function returns `TRUE` if the specified file is open:

```
Function IsFileOpen(fileName As String) As Boolean
'returns TRUE if file [fileName] is locked/open
    Dim filenum As Long
    On Error Resume Next
    filenum = FreeFile()
    Open fileName For Input Lock Read As #filenum 'try to open (lock) file
    Close filenum
    If Err = 0 Then Exit Function
    If Err <> 70 Then 'not "permission denied"
        MsgBox "Error " & Err & ": " & Err.Description
    Else
        IsFileOpen = True
    End If
End Function
```

This function returns `TRUE` if the any files within the specified folder are open.  Open files are listed in the Immediate Window.  (This function also requires function `IsFileOpen` from above.)

```
Function isFolderOpen(folderName As String) As Boolean
'returns TRUE if any files within folder [folderName] are locked/open
'names of open files are listed in the Immediate Window (CTRL+G to view)
    Dim dirStr As String
    If Right(folderName, 1) <> "\" Then folderName = folderName & "\"
    dirStr = Dir(folderName & "*.*", vbHidden)
    Do While dirStr <> ""
        If IsFileOpen(folderName & dirStr) Then
            isFolderOpen = True
            Debug.Print "File Open: " & folderName & dirStr
        End If
        dirStr = Dir
    Loop
End Function
```

---

### More Information

- MSDN : [**Name Statement**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/name-statement)
- MSDN : [**Open Statement**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/open-statement)
- MSDN : [**Dir Function**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/dir-function)

Comment: so the file doesn't seem open at least in my windows interface. However i have another macro that feeds a listbox with the files in the folder that uses objfso. Maybe i should change my question to how to determine if the file is open in a folder, either by the user or any other user(if it is in a shared drive).

Comment: @RaphaelYaghdjian - Try the procedures I added above (both are needed to check a folder).  Let me know how it works out; I'm curious what the issue is.

Comment: so i tried your code, it works in my immediate window when i try with the same folder string. If i manually open the file in the folder it tells me true when i run it. However when when i'm executing the Name x As y it returns False and still gives me the error.

Comment: @RaphaelYaghdjian - What kind of file is it?

Comment: @RaphaelYaghdjian - Just before your `Name x As y`, add 2 lines: `If isFolderOpen(x) Or isFolderOpen(y) Then Stop` and see what happens.  If this still doesn't indicate that a file is open, Reboot your computer ad try again.  Also just to confirm, all the folders/files in question are unshared and stored locally (not on a share or network drive), correct?

Comment: So usually a Word File, or a PDF file... it does not happen with exe file or some others. I tested manually. So the problem does not seem to be with my code itself as in my additional information above i explain that it gives me error sometimes when running in immediate window. I don't know if it is because im on Windows 10 but it gives me problems when i copy a Microsoft Office file to the folder and a Word instance opens in task manager even though the file itself is not open.

Comment: Are you saying just a regular, Windows copy & paste `CTRL+C` `CTRL+V` of a **closed** MS Word file from one folder to another, starts an instance of Word in the Task Manager?  Have you tried rebooting?

Comment: ...also, just to confirm, when you say a Word instance opens in the task manager, are you referring to the an instance called "***`filename.docx`* `- Microsoft Word`**" on the `Applications` tab, or an instance called "**`WINWORD32.EXE`**" on the `Processes` tab?

Comment: Yes to 1st question. And the instance is just called "Microsoft Word" in processes, differently from my Excel one that shows my Excel file open in a drop-down. Sorry i know it seems quite complicated and probably already out of the scope of my question. It seems some problem with when i copy a file it opens a word instance, more of a windows thing. As i just went to the folder of a recently copied word file trying to rename it and it does not allow me. Not sure if this happen to everyone or not. I will try a reboot and see.

Comment: **Yes, reboot please.**  I'm not saying that will solve the problem for sure but it's the simplest troubleshooting step there is and it does fix a lot of issues.  That should have been the **first** thing you tried, any time there's a file-lock type error (or any unexplained error, for that matter) -- or `43` minutes ago, when I suggested that the **first** time, or `37` minutes ago when I asked about it the **second** time.

Comment: Yeah thanks for your help. I just saw the second time you asked it, i commented something as you were adding that first comment suggesting to reboot. I rebooted it didn't work anyway. It is likely to be a problem with my windows. I will leave the question here anyway and have your answer as the definitive one as it would most likely solve my problem if it wasn't for some windows 10 problem i am having. Thanks for that, anyway your piece of code will help me improve my code for when someone else has something open in the folder. Sorry for the trouble.